# Cross Join in SQL 2005 with like

Tags: cross-join

Below are two queries. I get correct returns in Access but NO returns in SQL.  Is my syntax in the SQL version wrong? Curiously, even if I leave out the second part of the WHERE statement, the returned values don't make sense (i.e. last names = tblx.Last Name = Hull / tbly.Last Name = Morris)...Any ideas?

--SQL 2005

SELECT tblx.[Last Name], tblx.[First Name]
FROM tblx cross join tbly
WHERE (tblx.[Last Name] Like '%[tbly].[Last Name]%') AND (tblx.[First Name] Like '%Right([tbly].[First Name],3) %')

--Access 2007

SELECT tblx.[Last Name], tblx.[First Name]
FROM tblx cross join tbly
WHERE (((tblx.[Last Name]) Like "*" & [tbly].[Last Name] & "*") AND ((tblx.[First Name]) Like "*" & Right([tbly].[First Name],3) & "*"))

Comment: It should be:
SELECT tblx.[Last Name], tblx.[First Name] FROM tblx cross join tbly WHERE (((tblx.[Last Name]) Like '%' + [tbly].[Last Name]+'%') AND ((tblx.[First Name]) Like '%' + Right([tbly].[First Name],3) +'%'))
Same for Acess sql.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

SELECT tblx.[Last Name], tblx.[First Name] FROM tblx cross join tbly WHERE (((tblx.[Last Name]) Like '%' + [tbly].[Last Name]+'%') AND ((tblx.[First Name]) Like '%' + Right([tbly].[First Name],3) +'%'))

Same for Acess sql.